# SQLite exception

Tags: android, sqlite

I have problem with inserting values to my sqllite database.

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_METER = "create table "
        + TABLE_METER + " ( " 
        + METER_KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + METER_KEY_METER_ID + " text unique, "
        + METER_KEY_ACCOUNT_ID + " text, "
        + METER_KEY_MODEL + " text, "
        + METER_KEY_TYPE + " text, "
        + METER_KEY_LOCATION + " text, "
        + METER_KEY_ACCRUED + " double, "
        + METER_KEY_CURRENT + " double, "
        + METER_KEY_INSTALLATION_ACT_CODE + " text, "
        + METER_KEY_INSTALLATION_LOCATION_ID + " text );";
```

So my `METER_KEY_ID` is unique.

I am adding new meters and showing log with new inserting id.

```
public void addMeters(List<Meter> meters, String accountId) {
    mDb.beginTransaction();
    try {
        for(int i = 0; i < meters.size(); i++) {
            Log.d("VodomerDBHelper", meters.get(i).id);
            mDb.insert(TABLE_METER, null, createMeterValues(meters.get(i), accountId));
        }
        mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        mDb.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

My log shows me next:

```
03-24 13:13:27.126: D/VodomerDBHelper(7299): 29980
03-24 13:13:28.596: D/VodomerDBHelper(7299): 29981
03-24 13:13:29.396: D/VodomerDBHelper(7299): 29983
03-24 13:13:29.426: D/VodomerDBHelper(7299): 29982
03-24 13:13:29.756: D/VodomerDBHelper(7299): 29984
03-24 13:13:30.056: D/VodomerDBHelper(7299): 29985
```

So all values are different. But i have next exception

```
03-24 13:13:27.166: E/SQLiteDatabase(7299): Error inserting id=29980     installation_location_id=93129966 model=СКВ-15/Х ВIР-М account_id=3072460011 location=Сан.узел current=0.0 installation_act_code=29935 type=расход холодной вод  accrued=4.0
03-24 13:13:27.166: E/SQLiteDatabase(7299): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column id is not unique (code 19)
03-24 13:13:27.166: E/SQLiteDatabase(7299):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
03-24 13:13:27.166: E/SQLiteDatabase(7299):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
```

Next i check my sqllite database and everything is ok. New data is here and now problems.
But why the exception has been thrown?

Comment: The exception doesn't come from your loop, at least not on its first pass. Can you post the complete stacktrace that would indicate where you're calling the insert that causes the constraint violation?

Comment: Is the value for `METER_KEY_METER_ID` unique across your inserted values?

Comment: from the logcat, its pretty clear that METER_KEY_METER_ID 29980 is being inserted twice. Due to which, 'non unique' exception is being thrown.
May be you can check the List<Meters> meters variable for the data in it

Comment: @Atish Agrawal not clear for me. If it would be true we will see the duplicate values in log.

Comment: @chris Yes. All data that has been inserted is logging. And you can see that all data in log is distinct.

Comment: You have two columns you have a unique constraint on but are logging one value. You might want to check the other to see if that's violated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that i missed. i has been inserting those values one more time from other method.
Thanks for all.